# How can I retain a GridViewRow value?

Tags: c#, asp.net

My `GridView` is loaded with data from my database in a `DataSet`, which corresponds to `Label`s inside the `GridView`.

When users click the `Select` button on a `GridViewRow`, the button fills a `TextBox` outside the `GridView` from the selected row's column value.

After editing values in the `TextBox` outside my `GridView`, the user can click a button to move the new value from the `TextBox` back to the `GridView` (but not to the database).

My problem is: when I select the next row and do the same action, it clear the previous newly-added row data. It doesn't retain the previous row data.

I know it can be done by `ViewState` or `Session`, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: what code do you have .. also this sounds like a Binding Issue as well as the type of Isolation you are using.. do you utilize and Save() method that will update the changes to the database..? Please paste the code that you have where you are inteded or expected to see the database update changes

Comment: There could be many reasons for this - can you show your Gridview markup, and the logic you're using to bind data to it, as well as retain/save new data?

Answer (score 0):

check for `if(! ispostback)`  before filling data back to your grid. i am assuming that on click of select (Edit) button your page post back and then it fills value in textbox for edit and same time its refilling data in grid control also. so before filling value in grid control make sure its not postback.